# parsing command line arguments based on '='

Tags: java, command-line-arguments, apache-commons-cli

I am using [apache commons.cli](http://commons.apache.org/cli/) library to parse the command line arguments. The default parsing behavior is that it parses the arguments based on space. I am using ant to pass arguments to my Java program and the ant is using a slightly different syntax and is using `=` instead of space. How can I change the behavior of my parsing that it parses based on  `=`
and not space ? 
My parsing currently looks like this :

```
    Options options = new Options();
    options.addOption("Dkey", true, "some parameter");
    CommandLineParser parser = new PosixParser();
    CommandLine cmd = parser.parse(options, args);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the [usage examples page](http://commons.apache.org/cli/usage.html), especially the Ant example.

You could use the `OptionBuilder` and create an option for `D` which has 2 arguments.

For your case the adapted example from that page could look like this:

```
Option property  = OptionBuilder.withArgName( "key=value" )
                            .hasArgs(2)
                            .withValueSeparator()
                            .withDescription( "use value for given property" )
                            .create( "D" );
```

Here's the relevant JavaDoc with another example: http://commons.apache.org/cli/api-1.2/org/apache/commons/cli/OptionBuilder.html#withValueSeparator%28%29

```
Option opt = OptionBuilder.withValueSeparator().create('D');

CommandLine line = parser.parse(args);
String propertyName = opt.getValue(0);
String propertyValue = opt.getValue(1);
```

Comment: it complains when I use CommandLine line = parser.parse(args); only allows CommandLine line = parser.parse(options, args); ?

Comment: @comatose That might be a versioning issue: either you use an older version, they didn't update their doc yet or I accidentially linked old docs. - Or they just have an error in their documentation, they're humans after all :) - If `parser.parse(options, args)` works then use this.